# How to show additional weather stats, such as wind, in Office Outlook Weather Bar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, outlook-addin, weather

In Office Outlook 2016 there is a Weather Bar widget above the Calendar tab. This shows high and low of the temperature for today, tomorrow and the day after. It is possible to configure this to use either Celsius or Fahrenheit.

A sunny Saturday on a gloomy Thursday is a great motivator, and I would like to keep this. However, as an avid kitesurfer, I really want to know the wind stats (speed, direction, gusts) and tides (high, low, times and heights).

How can I get Outlook to do this for me (and the wider wind-junkie community)?

Comment: No, the widget is limited to the information you're seeing now.

Comment: Do we know of any add-ins or other tools that can replace this?

Comment: No, we don't. And software recommendations are off topic here. Try at [softwarerecs.se] but please do not cross-post. Delete this one first.